# Running multiple JIRA issues as Behat tests

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, jira, bdd, behat

I am using Behat and JIRA together to run automated tests. Currently I am able to run a single JIRA issue using:

$ bin/behat jira:ISSUE_NUMBER

In order to this, I am using the JIRA extension for Behat (http://extensions.behat.org/jira-extension/)

However, I am looking for a way to run a group of tests on my JIRA account. I need this to work similar to the @tags in behat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Girish Kini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible. After research, I have learnt that this feature is currently not supported by the jira extension. In the interim, try adding support for a comma separated list, eg jira:issue-1,issue-2,etc-n via the FeatureLoaderService.php.

sources: Anthon Pang via  vipsoft/JiraExtension [ GitHub ]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a version that included all the tickets that you wanted to run. Then in your behat.yml file specify that version using jql. Afterwhich you can run the following command.

> php bin/behat http://myserver.com:8080/